# Flash banners are not working in Chrome

Tags: html, flash, google-chrome

I have some Flash banners in my website and a few GIFs. Several days ago I noticed that the Flash is not working when browsing with Chrome. When browsing with IE all is ok.

This is the link to my website: http://batgalim.org.il/

This is an image describing the problem. Marked with red Xs are the missing banners
http://batgalim.org.il/banners_problem.jpg

[image: Banners]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a recent bug in chrome, per [this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=243290).

It hasn't been solved, but as I suspected, one user is reporting that a workaround is to use [SWF Object](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed Flash on your page.  It's really the best route to take anyway, it solves a lot of common problems with embedding Flash... at some point even Adobe made SWF object the default way to embed Flash apps (when using Flash Builder).