# "Error calling method on NPObject" on first page load

Tags: javascript, flash, google-chrome

since a few days there seems to be a problem with a audio player script (flash + javascript) on one of our pages that NEVER occured before and I changed absolutely nothing in the code (it has worked for a few years now) that could cause this issue.
We bought the audio player script a few years ago, and again, until a few days ago, it worked perfectly.

The error also behaves very strange. Let me explain...:

The page is [www.imatunes.de](http://www.imatunes.de) . You can see these small audio players on each article there.
Feel free to check out the code, got nothing to hide there.

My coworkers told me, that suddenly nothing happened if they clicked on the "Play" buttons. Normally, the script should start the flash player, which plays an audio file.

Now comes the "somehow" strange part:
My coworkers are all using Google Chrome. When they open the page in Chrome and click on a "Play" button, the JavaScript console throws the following error:
**"Error on calling method on NPObject".**
Googling that error says it has to do something with actionscript, cross-domain policies and such. But the error will get stranger...:

I'm using Firefox, and there it works FLAWLESS. But it also works on MY Google Chrome flawless, so it's very hard to debug (that's why I'm here to ask).

My coworkers also tried it on their home PCs, also running Google Chrome and such, and it also doesn't work there.

Now comes the "very" strange part:
When they get this error and reload the page via the browser controls (F5 or the reload button), it still won't work.
**But** if they browse around the page or just click on the logo in the header (which basically takes them to the home page again), the script magically works.
And on every other page except for the home page, it will work on first try.

As I said before, this started a few days ago - before that, everything worked just fine. And I really didn't change anything in the code.

So regarding the fact that it works after they browse around the page and return to the home page, it somehow seems like some sort of caching error. 
I really don't know how I could debug this, or what to do.

Thank your for every possible help in advance!

Comment: The fact that it started recently and never happened before, and that the symptoms are just plain wacky, makes me think it's Chrome's "Pepper" Flash player acting up yet again. This is a "modern" Flash plugin that is intended for use w/Chrome on Linux OS's, but it is also the default plugin on other OS's. To confirm whether it's pepper flash or not, you can disable it here: chrome://plugins (you will have the old style plugin installed too, which you can leave enabled).

Comment: Unfortunately, disabling the pepper flash plugin **didn't help**. But I would have never thought of that being a possible cause, so thank you anyways!

Comment: It just occurred to me there is another issue w/Chrome. I didn't put it together until I re-read your question and noticed you said the error occurs on the Javascript console. So you get the error when trying to call a Flash method from Javscript? And your page has multiple Flash objects on it? Could the problem be related to [this recent bug in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16867813/398606)?